# pyqt5 This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python

have a problem with PyQt5 Designer. I install PyQt with -pip install PyQt5 and then -pip install PyQt5-tools everything OK. But when i try to run Designer it open messagebox with error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized! how to deal with it?

1.Go to => Python38>lib>site-packages>PyQt5>Qt>plugins
2.In plugins copy platform folder
3.After that go to Python38>lib>site-packages>PyQt5_tools>Qt>bin
4.paste folder here . Do copy and replace.

I've tried this, but there's no (PyQt5_tools>Qt>bin) folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by installing Qt via Qt installer you can find it here:
[Qt installer download page](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)